# Передача данных между вьюшками (Python, Flask)

Tags: python, flask

Есть две въюшки. Одна получает инпут от юзера на странице, создаёт словарь, прорисовывает страницу и отдаёт данные созданный словарь в другую вьюшку которая дальше с ним работает. Как мне передать словарь из одной въюшки в другую.

```
@app.route("/game/")
def game():
    # сюда я должен его получит и проделать с ним манипуляцииreturn 
    render_template('game.html', data=data)

@app.route("/")
def page():
num = request.args.get("num")
if num:
    data = {"field": get_field(int(num)), "num": int(num),"chord": "0", "empty": '.', 'x': 'x', 'o': 'o', "moves": 1}
    return render_template('game.html', data=data) # эта создаёт словарь
return render_template('first_page.html')
```

И при условии, что в HTML работаю через ссылки:
по типу:

```html
{% else %}
<span><a href="{{ url_for('game')}}">
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/main.png')  }}" width='30px' height='15px'/></a>
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to pass a variable between Flask pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27611216/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Если `/game` у вас всегда параметры требует, то можно их явно в виде url параметров передавать (`/game?num=1&chord=0`):

```
@app.route('/game')
def game():
    data = dict(num=request.args.get('num'),
                chord=request.args.get('chord'))
    return render_template('game.html', data=data)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    num = request.args.get('num')
    if num:
        return redirect(url_for('game', num=int(num), chord='0'))
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Где `templates/index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Index</title>
<form>
  <input name="num">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<a href="{{ url_for('game', num=1, chord='0') }}">game</a>
```

и `templates/game.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Game</title>
<dl>
   <dt>Num
   <dd>{{ data.num }}
   <dt>Chord
   <dd>{{ data.chord }}
</dl>
```

---

Если хотите неявно передавать сгенерированное на сервере состояние,  можно сессию использовать (в cookies передаётся между запросами):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, session

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/game')
def game():
    return render_template('game.html', data=session.get('data') or {'num': 1, 'chord': '0'})


@app.route('/')
def index():
    num = request.args.get('num')
    if num:
        session['data'] = dict(num=int(num), chord='0')
        return redirect(url_for('game'))
    return render_template('index.html')


app.secret_key = '73870e7f-634d-433b-946a-8d20132bafac'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=3000, debug=True)
```

где `templates/index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Index</title>
<form>
  <input name="num">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<a href="{{ url_for('game') }}">game</a> <!-- data is from the current session -->
```

и `templates/game.html` тот же самый.

Answer (score 0):

**Используйте flask.g**

```
from flask import g
@app.route('/')
def page():
    ...  # Ваш код
    g.data = data

@app.route('/game/')
def game():
    data = getattr(g, 'data', None)
    if data is not None:
        ...  # Ваш код
    else:
        ...  # Ваш код в случае ошибки
```

---

Также можете использовать `redirect(url_for('game', data=data))`

В таком случае Вам нужно в параметрах к функции `game` передать аргумент data

```
def game(data=None):
    if data is not None:
        ...  # Ваш код
    else:
        ...  # Ваш код в случае ошибки
```

Comment: оба решения неверные. 1- `g` между запросами не сохраняется, поэтому `data` у вас всегда `None`. 2- `redirect(url_for('game', data=data))` передаст `data` как в url query, поэтому снова у вас `data` всегда `None`.

Comment: @jfs вопрос был про один контекст запроса, а не про несколько, а на счёт второго возможно Вы и правы

Comment: уже сам заголовок вопроса сам по себе более одного запроса предполагает (более одной "вьюшки"). Попробуйте создать минимальный, но полный пример кода с `g.data`  и убедитесь что не работает (много кода здесь не требуется, посмотрите на [полный пример в моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780568/23044)).

Answer (score 0):

Mr Morgan, спасибо что подсказал где искать.  Решил при помощи g и глобальных переменных. 
Может я тугой, но целый день провозился с этим моментом. Может кому пригодиться....

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, g
FIELD = []
NUM = 0


@app.route("/")
    def page():
    num = request.args.get("num")
    if num:
        global NUM
        NUM = int(num)
        global FIELD
        FIELD = get_field(NUM)

        return render_template('game.html', data=data) # эта создаёт словарь
return render_template('first_page.html')



@app.route("/game<pk>/<move>/<line>:<point>")
def game(pk, move, line, point):
    game_playing = Game.query.filter(Game.id == pk)
    if move == 0:
        field = getattr(g, 'field', None)
    else:
        field = FIELD
    return render_template('game.html', field=field, data=DATA, pk=pk)
```

и ещё, как оказалось должна быть такая штука, без которой g работать не будет

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.field = get_field(NUM)
```

Comment: здесь слишком много сломано, чтобы перечислять. Начните с исправления отступов.